# How to share Wifi connection using a USB adapter

Tags: networking, wireless, adapter

I am connecting to a Wifi of the university on my machine running Ubuntu 18.04.4. I bought a USB adapter DLINK 131 E1 to share the connection. The driver of the this adapter can be found [here](http://support.dlink.com.au/Download/download.aspx?product=DWA-131&type=Drivers).

Is it possible to share my Internet connection (on my PC that is connecting via Wifi) via the USB Adapter?

If it is possible, How can I achieve that? is there any software that can help me setup that?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

open a terminal and do the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap
cd create_ap
make install
```

based on your requirements, hit the following commands. For me eth0 is my ehthernet connection and wlan0 is my wifi card.

No passphrase (open network):

```
create_ap wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint
```

WPA + WPA2 passphrase:

```
create_ap wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

AP without Internet sharing:

```
create_ap -n wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

Bridged Internet sharing:

```
create_ap -m bridge wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

Bridged Internet sharing (pre-configured bridge interface):

```
create_ap -m bridge wlan0 br0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

Internet sharing from the same WiFi interface:

```
create_ap wlan0 wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

Choose a different WiFi adapter driver

```
create_ap --driver rtl871xdrv wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

No passphrase (open network) using pipe:

```
echo -e "MyAccessPoint" | create_ap wlan0 eth0
```

WPA + WPA2 passphrase using pipe:

```
echo -e "MyAccessPoint\nMyPassPhrase" | create_ap wlan0 eth0
```

Enable IEEE 802.11n

```
create_ap --ieee80211n --ht_capab '[HT40+]' wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

Client Isolation:

```
create_ap --isolate-clients wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

Systemd service
Using the persistent systemd service

Start service immediately:

```
systemctl start create_ap
```

Start on boot:

```
systemctl enable create_ap
```

Comment: If that is the fix it could be marked as a duplicate of many answers  https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%5Bwireless%5Dcreate_ap

Comment: The OP has two wireless interfaces, not a wifi and a cable like in this answer...